# How to prevent JTable cell from starting editing on certain key strokes?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am implementing Undo/Redo feature into my JTable but I have a problem with default behavior of JTable which starts editing a cell on any key press.

The problem is that it also starts editing on <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>.

How to prevent cell editing when these two keys are pressed?

NOTE: I have multiple panels with multiple tables inside one panel and I have tried overriding `isCellEditable()` but failed.

Comment: what happens at CTRL+Z and CTRL+Y?

Comment: Selected cell starts editing and adds the pressed character to it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the above clarification. Other users might not read the comment. [-From Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/14579036)

Comment: with this code `table = new JTable(model) {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   public boolean isCellEditable(int x, int y) {
    return false;
   }
  };` the table should not be editable at all (only programmatic). try this if its okay for the tables to not be editable by the user. if it does not help we will need code

Comment: It's not how it should work. I need all other key pressed other than CTRL+Z and CTRL+Y to start editing. My classes are all 1500+ lines and sending them here wouldn't help since it's the default behavior of JTable.

Comment: well. i tested it with and editable jtable and it only does this if i press ctrl-y but it does not append any character then. you could add keylistener to an not editable jtable. if you pess ctrl+y/z it does undo/redo. if you press anything else you set the row/cell/whatever editable and append the text (if wished to automatically append the character)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This example prevents a cell being edited on <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>. It does so by:

1. Overriding [`CellEditor.isCellEditable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/CellEditor.html#isCellEditable-java.util.EventObject-)
2. Checking whether the event object passed is an instance of [`KeyEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html)
3. If so, and the key pressed is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>, it returns false

---

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.EventObject;

import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;

public class JTableWithCtrlZ {
    private JTableWithCtrlZ( ) {}

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private static JTable createTable( ) {
        return new JTable( 10, 10 ) {
            @Override
            public TableCellEditor getDefaultEditor( Class<?> columnClass ) {
                return new DefaultCellEditor( new JTextField( ) ) {
                    @Override
                    public boolean isCellEditable( EventObject anEvent ) {
                        if( anEvent instanceof KeyEvent ) {
                            KeyEvent ke = (KeyEvent) anEvent;
                            if( ( ke.getKeyCode( ) == KeyEvent.VK_Z || ke.getKeyCode( ) == KeyEvent.VK_Y ) &&
                                ( ke.getModifiersEx( ) & KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK ) == KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK )
                                return false;
                        }

                        return super.isCellEditable( anEvent );
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }

    public static JFrame createFrame( ) {
        JPanel p = new JPanel( );
        p.setLayout( new BorderLayout( ) );
        p.add( new JScrollPane( createTable( ) ), BorderLayout.CENTER );
        p.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 250, 150 ) );

        JFrame f = new JFrame( );
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        f.setContentPane( p );
        f.pack( );
        return f;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createFrame( ).setVisible( true );
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I've been looking for. Thanks alot!

Comment: @MilosMisic You're welcome of course. I only answered the part where you prevent the editing. Catching the key events to undo/redo is another matter.

Comment: @MilosMisic Good to hear! Good luck!